# How to replace default properties in library

Tags: java, properties

I am making the library that has the default properties in the file default.properties.

```
private static String defPropertyPath = "/database.properties";
```

I want to ask if this file can be replaced by the program that use my library. So the program will define the properties with the same name default.properties that will replace the properties from library. I created the default.properties in the program where i use the library, but the library is still loading the properties from their package.

edit:
I read the properties file via input stream:

```
  InputStream ins = DbProperties.class.getResourceAsStream(defPropertyPath);
    if (ins == null) {
        logger.error("Can't find properties:" + pathToProperties);
        return;
    }
```

Edit: File structure:

```
DbLibrary.jar
/
/database.properties
/src


MyApplication.jar
/
/database.properties
/src
/lib/DbLibrary.jar
```

My application use the DbLibrary.jar and wants to force this library to use database.properties from MyApplication and not from the DbLibrary.

Comment: Please post your code which accesses the above file. How do you read it?

Comment: Your custom default.properties must be _before_ the library in the classpath -- this way you are sure it will be read before the library's one

Answer (score 1):

May be much clearer if your library exports some API that allows the user of your library to invoke an init method at any time.

```
public static void init(Properties p) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, I also have something like this, I only wonder if this properties replacement is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough information to answer your question, but I'm going to guess that perhaps you included the "database.properties" file in the jar with your application. If you did that, the application will always read the file from the jar, and not from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to override the properties file in these projects which include your library.

Comment: Yes, but how? the file structure which is in the question test, doesn't help.